# Create couchdb doc using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, couchdb

```
var post_data ={ "task_list": $scope.task_list,"uri": $scope.uri }
$http({method: 'POST',url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/tasklist/'+$scope.task_list, data: post_data})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("POST SUCCESS")
                alert("Successfully added");
             })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("POST ERROR", data)
             })
    }
    } );
```

When I compile the above code it shows an error of

> 127.0.0.1:5984/tasklist/text:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/tasklist/text 400 (Bad Request)
>   admin.html:63 POST ERROR Object {error: "bad_request", reason: "Referer header required."}

Why does it show this? Any remedy for this?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the error message. "Referer header required."

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need include headers in the post data. Since your post url expecting Referer.

```
var post_data = {
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/tasklist/'+$scope.task_list,
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'json',
'Referer': 'http://www.example.com/app/index.html' //include headers
},
data: { "task_list": $scope.task_list,"uri": $scope.uri }
}

$http(post_data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("POST SUCCESS")
            alert("Successfully added");
         })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("POST ERROR", data)
         });
```